# Hibernate component OneToOne mapping using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following table schema.

```
Employee (id int primary key, addressId int);
Address (id int primary key, line1 varchar(99), line2 varchar(99));
```

And Classes:

```
Employee {
int id;
Address address;}

Address {
String line1;
String line2;}
```

How will make a OneToOne component mapping from Employee to Address using annotations?

Comment: This post is what you need: -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314578/need-an-example-of-a-primary-key-onetoone-mapping-in-hibernate

Comment: I am not sure how the posting Rohit mentions related to this!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
public class Address {
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
}
```

Comment: I need Address to be a component (That means I need to use '@Embeddable' for Address. In that case I will not be able to use @Table for Address)

Comment: Your table schema saying something different.