# Hibernate reference mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table Marital Status with values "single", "married", etc.

I have a table Person with marital_status_id as foreign key.

How do I mapped this one? Any help will be appreciated as I am new in Hibernate. Or I dont need this one since there isn't of a relation between Person and Marital Status but just a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a marital status does not need a separate table (does it? really?). It can be handled with a single character (very efficient)

However, in your case,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
Class Person(){
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="MARITAL_STATUS_ID")
    MaritalStatus maritalStatus;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MARITAL_STATUS")
Class MaritalStatus(){
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="maritalStatus")
    Set<Person> persons;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I just use character to do away with unnecessary tables.

Answer (score 1):

Marital Status should be expressed as enum in Java to exclude unnecessary joins since there are not so many options and they will never change.
Check `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html

Comment: It must work because basically all it does is saves value as a string - from the point of database there is no difference between java's string variable and enum - this concerns only persistent provider. Be sure to select postresql dialect in your persistence provider settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified whether you insist to have one-to-one relationship or you don't care , and also if you prefer using Enum instead of a Class.

This Link provides some useful information on one-to-one mapping in hibernate, if you want to have such relationship between your tables: [one-to-one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314578/need-an-example-of-a-primary-key-onetoone-mapping-in-hibernate)

However hibernate one-to-one mapping is not much recommended, and you could simply use a one-to-many mapping just like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Private MaritalStatus;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MaritalStatus")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id; 

    @ManyToOne
    Person person = new Person();
}
```

This approach is much simple , but you may prefer to have an Enum instead of class and map your tables using enums. That approach is a bit more difficult to implement and this post provides you all the stuff you need : [Mapping enum to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735732/mapping-enum-to-a-table-with-hibernate-annotation)

Comment: I think you have your `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like below

Person entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "Person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "marital_status_id")
    private MaritalStatus  maritalStatus;

}
```

Marital status entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "MaritalStatus")
public class MaritalStatus {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
}
```